# How to print vertically aligned text

Tags: java, string, formatting, alignment

I want to print an output of the following format in a file..

```
1 Introduction                                              1
 1.1 Scope                                                  1
 1.2 Relevance                                              1
   1.2.1 Advantages                                         1
     1.2.1.1 Economic                                       2
   1.2.2 Disadvantages                                      2
2 Analysis                                                  2
```

I cannot get the page numbers to align vertically in a line. How to do this??

Comment: Will the file be displayed in a fixed size font?

Comment: The default font size is used always.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to left-justify the first column, and right-justify the second column.

Here's an example:

```
    String[] titles = {
        "1 Introduction",
        " 1.1 Scope",
        " 1.2 Relevance",
        "    1.2.1 Advantages",
        "      1.2.1.1 Economic",
        "    1.2.2 Disadvantages",
        "2 Analysis",
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%-30s %4d",
            titles[i],
            i * i * i // just example formula
        ));
    }
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/MP7Hr)):

```
1 Introduction                    0
 1.1 Scope                        1
 1.2 Relevance                    8
    1.2.1 Advantages             27
      1.2.1.1 Economic           64
    1.2.2 Disadvantages         125
2 Analysis                      216
```

The format `%-30s %4d` left-justifies (`-` flag) the first argument with width of 30, and right-justifies the second argument with width of 4.

#### API links

- [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 6):

Usually, with a String format specifier that enforces a minimum width:

```
someStream.write(String.format("%60s %3d", sectionName, pageNumber));
```

Comment: I had tried this. But it just types out page numbers after 60 spaces always. So the line numbers are not getting aligned vertically.