# How can I print my array in a certain way?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm wanting to print my arrays in a list. That will look like this.

```
      Word:        Count:
      Myths             2
         Of            15
  Babylonia            25
```

I can't seem to figure out how to print it the correct way, here is the code I have so far. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
package program6;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Program6 {

static String[] stringArray = new String[100];
static int[] intArray = new int[100];
static String fileName = "myths.txt";
static int currentWordIndex = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

      while (input.hasNext()){
        String word = input.next();
        boolean alreadyExists = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentWordIndex; i++) {

            if(stringArray[i].equals(word)){
                alreadyExists = true;
                intArray[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }


      if(!alreadyExists && currentWordIndex <100){
        stringArray[currentWordIndex] = word;
        intArray[currentWordIndex++] = 1;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Myths of Babylonia and Assyria");
    System.out.println("Word:          Count:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your correct way of output ?

Comment: I had in the top of my post my correct outcome in which I would like it to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a format and use a loop

```
System.out.println("Myths of Babylonia and Assyria");
System.out.println("Word:\t\tCount:");
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.lengthl i++){
    System.out.printf("%s\t\t%d\n", stringArray[i], intArray[i]);

}
```

Edit with right aligntment

```
    System.out.println("Myths of Babylonia and Assyria");
    System.out.printf("%10s%10s\n", "Word", "Count");
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%10s%10d", array1[i], array2[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Edit: Using a method for other books**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    printCounts("myth.txt", "Babylonia and Assyria");
    System.out.println();
    printCounts("someOther.txt", "Some Other Title");
    System.out.println();
    printCounts("another.txt", "Another Title");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printCounts(String filename, String title) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String[] stringArray = new String[100];
    int[] intArray = new int[100];
    int currentWordIndex = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.next();
        boolean alreadyExists = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentWordIndex; i++) {

            if (stringArray[i].equals(word)) {
                alreadyExists = true;
                intArray[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!alreadyExists && currentWordIndex < 100) {
            stringArray[currentWordIndex] = word;
            intArray[currentWordIndex++] = 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.printf("%10s%10s\n", "Word", "Count");
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%10s%10d", stringArray[i], intArray[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want less space in between, just delete a `\t`

Comment: Yeah now I just have to fix it to where they all print in the same spot, the end of each word should end at the colon on Word: and each number should end at the colon on Count:

Comment: The number 10 signifies not many characters are in the line. It it used for alignment. So if any word has more than 10 characters, the format will be off. If you have words with more than 10 characters, you need to change all the 10s to the length of the longest word

Comment: Ah I see thank you, so that's one book, if I wanted to add two others, would I have to make two other methods with the exact same stuff except different names?

Comment: If you have them in different arrays then yes, you need to do the same for every book.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42622/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-user2934545)

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing

```
System.out.println();
```

it is actually printing a new line at the end of your output.

Try using

```
System.out.print("foo ");
System.out.println("bar");
```

Have look at this [page](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) which explains the use of System.printf to align columns.

```
System.out.printf( "%-15s %15s %n", heading1, heading2);
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the column problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays have 100 elements, so lots of Zeros get printed, use [Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) to create smaller arrays.
For table format, use [printf](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html).

So you should replace the following code:

```
System.out.println("Word:          Count:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
System.out.println();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

with:

```
        String[] stringArray2 = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray, totalWordCount);
        int[] intArray2 = Arrays.copyOf(intArray, totalWordCount);

        stringArray = null;
        intArray = null;


        System.out.println("Myths of Babylonia and Assyria");
        System.out.printf("\n%15s%15s", "Word:","Count:");
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("\n%15s%15d", stringArray2[i], intArray2[i]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to right justify your columns. According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177697/how-to-print-vertically-aligned-text), columns left justified with a negative sign in front of them and right justfified without. You want your print statement to look something like this:

```
System.out.printf("%60s %3d", stringArray[i], intarray[i]));
```

You can vary the column width this way.

In addition: Someone mentioned you can avoid printing a line at the end of each statement by using `print` instead of `println`.

Comment: What is someStream? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2934545 Sorry, I was so focused on the spacing issue I missed the fact that the output statement wasn't very clear at this level. This may be more clear, using System.out.printf and println instead.

Comment: @user2310289 Lol sorry, intergalactic law prevents me from directly referencing other posts as posts are transient.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Program6 {

static String fileName = "myths.txt";
private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    while (input.hasNext()){
        String word = input.next();
        if ( map.containsKey(word) ){
            int temp = map.get(word) + 1;
            map.put(word, temp);
        } else {
            map.put(word, 1);
        }
    }

    // get all the set of keys
    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();

    // iterate through the key set and display key and values
    System.out.printf("%-10s\t\t%s\n", "Word", "Count:");
    for (String key : keys) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s\t\t%d\n", key, map.get(key));
    }

}
}
```